# Salesforce flow formula character limit reached

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a formula on a flow and it exceeds the character limit, so I was wondering it it would be possible to in to 2 formulas e.g formula 1 and formula 2 then use a 3rd formula to refer to the 1st and 2nd formula. If this can be done what would the formula be on the 3rd formula.

Any help with this would greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: short answer: nope

Comment: Can you add further detail, such as what are you trying to roll up or solve? What's the context? Do you have the formula that's too long?

Comment: The answer to this question is correct, there is no shortcut. You'll have to share the formula so that people can help you decrease its compiled size.

Answer (score 1):

This would not work. This is mentioned in the documentation clearly [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.formula_field_limits.htm&type=5)

> Compile size limit—Formula fields can’t exceed 5,000 bytes when compiled. The compile size is the size of the formula (in bytes) including all of the fields, values, and **formulas it references**. There is no direct correlation between the compile size and the character limit. Some functions, such as TEXT, DATEVALUE, DATETIMEVALUE, and DATE significantly increase the compile size.

So, the size of the third formula would be

```
F1 Size + F2 Size + F3 Size
```

You best bet would be to calculate this field using automation keeping in mind all trigger points (if you are using parent fields then you need to take that in account as well)